Manipulating 2d arrays in C++ and having trouble iterating through all of the data to create new arrays / go through the loops for the operation
I am writing a program for C++ that takes the user input with the first line containing the n integer ranging from 1-9 that informs on the grid size for the following data. then the grid with n number of columns and rows follows. Next is an integer m detailing how many operations will occur on the array with each of those following on the next line for m lines. I think I am having difficulty with extracting the data and telling the loop to stop and repeat again. My code is the following:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
// GLOBAL CONSTANTS
const size_t MAX = 9;               /// Maximum dimension of a grid

// PROTOTYPES HERE
void swap_rows(int grid[][MAX], size_t a, size_t b, size_t size);
void swap_columns(int grid[][MAX], size_t a, size_t b, size_t size);
void increment_grid(int grid[][MAX], size_t size);
void decrement_grid(int grid[][MAX], size_t size);
void transpose_grid(int grid[][MAX], size_t size);

int main() {
    // Variable declaration
int case_num = 1;
int grid[MAX][MAX];
int n;                          // size of array taken from int
int m;
string op;

    // ** input *****************************************************
    do {
        cin >> n;
        cin.clear();
        if (n < 0 && n > 9){
            cin.fail();
        }
    // ** process ***************************************************
        for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
            for (size_t j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
                cin >> grid[i][j];            // take in data to make grid
            }
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin >> m;            // input num of operations

        // using for loop to apply operation to grid and print
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {      //iterate through list m times
            cin >> op;
            if (op == "row") {
                int a;
                int b;
                cin >> a >> b;
                swap_rows(grid, a, b, n);    // for zero-based inputs
            } else if (op == "col"){
                int a;
                int b;
                cin >> a >> b;
                swap_columns(grid, a, b, n);
            } else if (op == "inc"){
                increment_grid(grid, n);
            } else if (op == "dec"){
                decrement_grid(grid, n);
            } else if (op == "transpose"){
                transpose_grid(grid, n);
            }
        }
    // ** Output ****************************************************
            cout << "Case #" << case_num << endl;
            case_num++;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++){        // print new array
                for (size_t j = 0; j < MAX; j++){
                    cout << grid[i][j];
                    cout << '\n';
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        } while (cin.good());                                  // continue loop
    return 0;
}

/// @brief the function swaps two rows in a given grid.
///
/// @param [in,out] grid - the grid in which rows are to be swapped
/// @param a - the first row to be swapped (zero-based index)
/// @param b - the second row to be swapped (zero-based index)
/// @param size - The size of the grid (number of rows/ columns).
/// @return none
void swap_rows(int grid[][MAX], size_t a, size_t b, size_t size) {
    int temp;
    // go through every column
    for (size_t col = 0; col < size; col++) {
    // swap [a] [col] with [b][col] use temp variable to store a variable
        temp = grid[a][col];
        grid[a][col] = grid[b][col];
        grid[b][col] = temp;        // declare temp variable to [b]
    }

}

/// @brief the function swaps two columns in a given grid.
///
/// @param [in,out] grid - the grid in which columns are to be swapped
/// @param a - the first column to be swapped (zero-based index)
/// @param b - the second column to be swapped (zero-based index)
/// @param size - The size of the grid (number of rows/ columns).
/// @return none
void swap_columns(int grid[][MAX], size_t a, size_t b, size_t size) {
    int temp;
    // go through every row
    for (size_t row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    // swap [row] [a] with [row][b] use temp variable to store a variable
        temp = grid[row][a];
    // declare b variable to [a] declare temp variable to [b]
        grid[row][a] = grid[row][b];
        grid[row][b] = temp;
    // increase i and repeat loop until array is finished
    }
}

/// @brief the function increments each element in the grid by 1, wrapping 
/// around to 0 at 10
///
/// @param [in,out] grid - the grid to be incremented
/// @param size - The size of the grid (numbers of rows/columns
/// @return none
void increment_grid(int grid[][MAX], size_t size) {
    // go through every row in every column
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            grid[i][j]++;       //increment the element

            if (grid[i][j] > 9) {
                grid[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

/// @brief the function decrements each element in the grid by 1, wrapping
/// around to 9 at -1
///
/// @param [in,out] grid - the grid to be decremented
/// @param size - The size of the grid (numbers of rows/columns
/// @return none
void decrement_grid(int grid[][MAX], size_t size) {
    // go through every row in every column
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            grid[i][j]--;       //decrement the element

            if (grid[i][j] < 0) {
                grid[i][j] = 9;
            }
        }
    }
}

/// @brief the function transposes the given grid
///
/// @param [in,out] grid - the grid to be incremented
/// @param size - The size of the grid (numbers of rows/columns
/// @return none
void transpose_grid(int grid[][MAX], size_t size) {
    int temp;
    // loop should start at row 2, go through every row
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++){
        for (size_t j = 1; j < i; j++){
            temp = grid[i][j];
            grid[j][i] = grid[i][j];
            grid[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

I have tried changing the loop variable and what the while statement would hold. I also tried debugging errors was having difficulty with the array selecting the correct data.
sample input would look as follows:
4
1234
5678
1234
5678
1
transpose
3
000
111
000
2
row 1 2
inc
0

how can I better fix my code to produce the proper outcome and function properly

First, I'd suggest that you make your program say what input it expects

Also, read the open letter about homework: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite C++ forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

n < 0 && n > 9 in that do loop in main -- can you think of a value of n that is both less than 0 and greater than 9?  Common typo. Should be n < 0 || n > 9. Even better, n < 0 || n > MAX.

for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++){ Should be using n there, not MAX. Same on next line.

main is doing three different things: it reads the grid data, manipulates it, and displays the result. That should be three separate functions, called from main one after the other. Begin by writing the function that displays the result; create grid with fixed data and display it. Once that's working, write the function that reads the grid data. Once that's working, write the function that manipulates it. The function that manipulates it has two parts: reading instructions and applying them. Again, start with applying a single manipulation. Get them all working. Then add the instructions

A few remarks after reading the first lines of main :
if (n < 0 && n > 9)

I guess you meant || : this statement in not possible
Your example input is not valid : size 4 means a grid of 4 by 4 = 16 inputs expected, you enter "transpose" way too soon...
   // ** process ***************************************************
        for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
            for (size_t j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
                cin >> grid[i][j];            // take in data to make grid
            }

Moreover because you ask for a size (user entered the "n" variable) but are using MAX in your loops...
This relates to my 1st comment : I'd suggest that you make your program say what input it expects so that you understand better what's going on, before using a debugger, that would be a further step to "how can I better fix my code", but I think not yet necessary.
Also, as @mikeb said, "read the open letter about homework: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems"
Good luck!

This is C++ so if you have a grid, model a grid as a class and add operations to it. Do not muck around with freestanding "C" like arrays (that loose all size information and are very easy to create bugs with).
Then use C++'s array type and it swap function to implement your functionality. (it shows WHAT you want to do much better)
And please get your teacher to teach you C++.
Also do not use using namespace std; in code.
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

static constexpr std::size_t GridSize = 3ul;


class Grid
{
public: 
    Grid( const std::array<std::array<int,GridSize>,GridSize>& cells ) :
        m_cells{std::move(cells)}
    {
    }

    void SwapColumuns(std::size_t from, std::size_t to)
    {
        //todo check input
        for(std::size_t row{0ul}; row < GridSize; ++row)
        {
            std::swap(m_cells[row][from], m_cells[row][to]);
        }
    }

    void SwapRows(std::size_t from, std::size_t to)
    {
        //todo check input
        for(std::size_t column{0ul}; column < GridSize; ++column)
        {
            std::swap(m_cells[from][column], m_cells[to][column]);
        }
    }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const Grid&);

private:
    std::array<std::array<int,GridSize>,GridSize> m_cells{};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const Grid& grid)
{
    for(const auto& row : grid.m_cells)
    {
        for(const auto& cell : row)
        {
            std::cout << cell;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return os;
}


int main()
{
    Grid grid{{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}}};
    std::cout << grid << "\n";
    
    grid.SwapColumuns(0,1);
    std::cout << grid << "\n";
    
    grid.SwapRows(1,2);
    std::cout << grid << "\n";
}

